# Give a checkbox an integer value and store in JavaDB

Tags: java

I am currently working on a small program that allows the ordering of items and the total cost to be stored in a JavaDB.

I have managed to successfully store integer values into the database but the cost amount for the items are not correct. It seems like when the check box is selected it is counting that as a value on top of the set value. Would anyone be able to take a look and see where I am going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHuew.png

Comment: There's a huge amount of redundant code here, that's irrelevant to your question. You're far more likely to get helpful responses if you reduce it to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip i'll reduce the code now. It's mainly the code within    btnOrderActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) that I think is the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone has a solution for this problem? I have been working on this for the past few hours and it still is not having the correct total cost based on item price :S  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I think I can see your problem. Reducing the code a bit further, you have:

```
int fanta = 1;
int crisps = 1;
int beer = 2;
int wine = 3;
int water = 0;

...

if(btnFanta.isSelected()) fanta++;
if(btnCrisps.isSelected()) crisps++;
if(btnBeer.isSelected()) beer++;
if(btnWine.isSelected()) wine++;
if(btnWater.isSelected()) water++;

rs.updateInt("TotalCost", fanta + crisps + beer + wine + water);
```

So, if nothing is selected, you're adding up all the values: `1 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 0 = 7`, and inserting that. If Fanta is selected, you first increment the value of `fanta`, making it 2, then add it to the values of all the other snacks: `2 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 0 = 8`, which is what you're seeing in the database when you select Fanta.

Hopefully that makes sense, and I'm guessing that's not what you want. I'd suggest that one solution would be to add a new variable, say, `totalCost`, and add the values to *that* if the relevant checkbox is selected, so, you'd end up with something like:

```
int fanta = 1;
int crisps = 1;
...
int totalCost = 0;
...
if(btnFanta.isSelected()) totalCost += fanta;
if(btnCrisps.isSelected()) totalCost += crisps;
...
rs.updateInt("TotalCost", totalCost);
```

(In case you're not familiar with the `+=` syntax, it's the same as saying `totalCost = totalCost + fanta`, i.e. you're adding `fanta` to whatever `totalCost` was previously.)

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this answer. The database is now storing the correct values for all items, even if multiples are selected. You have no idea how much time i have worked on this small issue. Also, thank you for explaining the solution, that has gone a long way to help me understand why it wasn't working in the first place. +1

Comment: _"You have no idea how much time i have worked on this small issue"_ - welcome to programming :)